# Integrating Facebook Audience Network

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I am integrating facebook ads in my app. I had create a palcement id and put code in my app. I used facebook audience network sdk. Should i have to include facebook sdk?

My placement status said Enabled for testing and received ad request recently
[image]

Then why it is displaying  send ad request here.
[image]

Also is my code correct to display ad at bottom of viewpager in both tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Linkto.be"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/accent"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="15dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/banner_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Facebook SDK to use Audience Network SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Use Audience Network SDK only if your app is with good traffic, there is one thing to know before motivational with FAN.

FAN policy strictly require app must live on playstore or appstore.

so, if you are integrate fan ads in your app then for any reason you unpublished,remove, suspend, or change fan sdk to any other adnetwork. you will indirectly violating facebook policy.because facebook has no mechanism to delete app from FAN Dashboard,

multiple app violence your facebook account will disabled, and to enable account you have to again activate all app with facebook audience network.

think in case of app suspend you can't activate same app with same package.so you can't resolve this issue ever.